# How to use perl to get information about a video?

Tags: perl, video

1. Verify whether the input url was obtained
2. get the url
3. see if the url was redirected
4. get meta tags as key-value pairs
5. get video tags as a list
6. url of the next suggested video

I tried Video::Info which provides the general information. However I don't know how to get things like whether it is redirected or not, the tags and the next video. Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to parse a URL, or read the header information in a video file? These would be two very different questions.

Comment: ... or how to parse a Youtube page.

Comment: Yes, This would be for a Youtube page

Comment: and this is not for a video file as such, more like for an URL which has a video

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`CGI`](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) module. Perhaps this will get you started with the general process:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI;

my $cgi = CGI->new('metadata=abc&nextVideo=efg&foo=bar&blah=etc');
my @URLQueryKeys = $cgi->param;

foreach my $URLQueryKey (@URLQueryKeys) { 
    print Dumper $URLQueryKey;
    print Dumper $cgi->param($URLQueryKey);
}
```